# How to run a java program faster?

Tags: java

I was wondering if a simple program with no threads can run faster on some computers which have many cores? or on a cluster of linux servers?
Recently I have run my algorithm which has to process billions of IP packets on my PC(core i7 with 16GB RAM) and it took 1881 minutes to finish processing. Then I thought its good to run the algorithm on clusters of linux servers each node with 10 processors and 48GB RAM to get the results quicker. However, there is no big difference between the two experiments. 
Can someone comments what I am missing?

Comment: Is your program CPU-bound or IO-bound? could you run top command to see how many cores you are using?

Comment: The answer is: "it depends", on your code, the input data and the way you distribute your task, and some other things too. Since none of these details are given... well, it depends

Comment: Maybe you're looking for Hadoop?

Comment: *I was wondering if a simple program with no threads* - Well, you need atleast one thread, the *main Thread*. If you want to make use of *several cores*, you need several threads. Only then your program will run substantially faster.

Comment: @Jens, or others voting to close - is there something wrong with current answers? I don't see why this would be too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your algorithm actually makes use of those multiple instances and extra memory, there shouldn't be a lot of difference. Parallel programming is an art of its own, and a "regular", single-threaded program doesn't just change into parallel one by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single thread of execution more cores, CPU or machines won't help. Only a faster CPU would speed things up, and that only if your process is CPU-bound, and not IO-bound.

First you should check, where your processing time is spent, in CPU, or waiting for IO. If you have a significant amount of CPU usage, you can try to parallelize your work, i.e. split the data into chunks, and have different thread resp. machines process them in parallel.